# Detect DragEnd in CustomScrollView flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, customscrollview

I want to detect vertical end of dragging of a `CustomScrollView` what I did was something like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {}
  child: CustomScrollView(...)
);
```

but it's not working, it seems like these two widgets have conflicts, I'm looking for a workaround with this issue

Answer (score 3):

Using a `GestureDetector` is not the correct way, here is a way of triggering a method when you stop dragging your scroll view:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  _onEndScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    print('Stopped Dragging');
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          _onEndScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        ...List<Widget>.generate(
          100,
          (index) => ListTile(title: Text(index.toString())),
        )
      ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Simply wrap your scroll view inside a `NotificationListener` widget then you will be able to get any notification from your scroll view and you only need to manage your action depending on the notification's type. (I return `false` at the end of `onNotification` to keep listening to upcoming notification.)

[Test the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/357562af86e03b83f3953aa7439b2430)

Comment: Yeah I've tried that one before, but it has problems, first I can't detect the velocity unless Scroll is ended, second I wanna call scrollcontroller.animateTo() in _onEndScroll which somehow can't be done, it seems like I have to update my question or delete it

Comment: Yeah you should create another question with those details as they were not mentionned firsthand.

Comment: in order for me to delete this, I think you have to delete your answer too